# Как вычислить максимальное количество дней между действиями?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть DataFrame, в одном из столбцов которого, хранятся даты действий в виде:

```
['2020-06-16 02:31:10', '2020-07-16 02:31:10', '2020-09-16 02:31:10', '2020-10-16 02:31:10']
```

Надо найти максимальный промежуток времени между действиями в днях и записать в новый столбец.

В данном примере это `'2020-09-16 02:31:10' - '2020-07-16 02:31:10' = 62 дня`

Подскажите, как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: А зачем вам столбец с одинаковыми значениями?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
max_days = df['Date'].diff().dt.days.abs().max()
```

Answer (score 1):

[datetime.strptime(строка, формат)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) — создает «date» объект из строки.

```
from datetime import datetime

arr = ['2020-06-16 02:31:10', '2020-07-16 02:31:10', '2020-09-16 02:31:10', '2020-10-16 02:31:10']

max_interval = 0 # в секундах

for k in range(1, len(arr)):
    prev_date = datetime.strptime(arr[k-1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    this_date = datetime.strptime(arr[k], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    diff = abs( (this_date - prev_date).total_seconds() )

    max_interval = max(diff, max_interval)
    
    print( diff ) # Test

print( max_interval / 60 / 60 // 24 ) # Перевод обратно в дни.
```

* Предполагается, что даты в массиве изначально отсортированы.